# Find key different from given key when iterating list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries and in each one of them the key `site` exists.
So in other words, this code returns `True`:

```
all('site' in site for site in summary)
```

Question is, what will be the pythonic way to iterate over the list of dictionaries and return `True` if a key different from `site` exists in any of the dictionaries?

**Example**: in the following list I would like to return `True` because of the existence of `cost` in the last dictionary BUT, I can't tell what will be the other key, it can be `cost` as in the example and it can be other strings; random keys for that matter.

```
[
    {"site": "site_A"},
    {"site": "site_B"},
    {"site": "site_C", "cost": 1000}
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all dictionaries have the key `site`, the dictionaries have a length of at least 1. The presence of *any other key* would increase the dictionary size to be greater than 1, test for that:

```
any(len(d) > 1 for d in summary)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just check, for each dictionary `dct`:

```
any(key != "site" for key in dct)
```

If you want to check this for a list of dictionaries `dcts`, shove another `any` around that: `any(any(key != "site" for key in dct) for dct in dcts)`

This also makes it easily extensible to allowing multiple different keys. (E.g. `any(key not in ("site", "otherkey") for key in dct)`) Because what's a dictionary good for if you can only use one key?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit longer version, but it gives you what you need. Just to give more options:

```
any({k: v for k, v in site.items() if k != 'site'} for site in summary)
```